# "No instance of overload function"

Tags: c++, function, overloading

My understanding of this error is that the arguments in the prototype and header don't match that of the header, however in my code those things match. I'm not sure what I'm missing here? Error on "showInfo(info, SIZE);"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;
int main();
void showInfo(Author info[], const int &);


struct BookInfo 
{
    string title; 
    double price;
};


struct Author
{
    string name;
    BookInfo books[SIZE];
};


int main()
{
    Author info[] = { {"NONE", {{"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE",      0.00}}},
                  {"NONE", {{"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE", 0.00}}},
                  {"NONE", {{"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE", 0.00}, {"NONE", 0.00}}},
                };
showInfo(info,SIZE);
return 0;
}

void showInfo(Author info[], const int&)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << info[i].name << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << info[i].books[j].title << endl;
        cout << info[i].books[j].price << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, those things don't match, actually.

The second parameter to `showInfo()` is a reference to a mutable integer.

You're trying to pass a reference to a `const` integer: `const int SIZE`.

Change `showInfo`'s 2nd paramter to a `const int &`. Might as well make it a plain `int`, actually. I don't see how passing a reference here accomplishes anything useful.

Comment: You must've made a mistake. Feel free to post another question, showing the new version of your code.

Comment: I'll update my original post, don't wanna take up stackoverflow with repeat questions!

Comment: Whenever I changed SIZE in the function call to int or const int, I got the "Type name not allowed" error

Comment: The other bug in your code that you're using the `Author` type before you declare it. You need to declare the `Author` class first, before declaring a function that takes this class as a parameter. And you should've kept the name of the function parameter; although since you used the same name as the global variable, it would still work. Still, nevertheless, you need to spend more time reading a good C++ book.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the helpful tips :). I'll definitely go through the chapter again. Thanks again!